# optimize heavy website CSS3 animations for mobile devices

Tags: css, optimization, css-animations, mobile-browser

I'm working on a responsive website with lots of CSS3 animations (keyframes).

As much as it works good in a desktop Chrome browser, the site is too heavy for mobile and crashing it's browser or even sometimes restart the device LOL.

I'm new to both responsive and CSS animations, and will like to get your help to optimize the animations so they will work on mobile devices without crashing them.

I already changed all my animations (keyframes) from using position top/left to transform translate3D.
And I also set the animation-play-state to "paused" by default, and changing it to "running" only when you get to the area of the element (when it's in viewport).

What more can I do please? or, do I can't do anything about that and should always pause the animations on mobile devices?

You welcome to answer me in general, or visit the site in the next link -

* DO NOT open it in a mobile, it may restart your device! *

Open it in latest Chrome or Firefox: http://goo.gl/BVsVH7

Again I'm new to both responsive and mobile, and I have no idea what I should and shouldn't do.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is hard to make this work well on mobile devices today.

I ran your website on google pagespeed and there are plenty of stuff you can make better. Paste your url there and you'll get a bunch of tips for optimization.

[Google PageSpeed Insights](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Comment: Thank you Jimmie for taking the time and checking it, google pagespeed tool looks good, I will try to learn from it and improve my sites.
So for now unfortunately I will just disable all CSS3 animations for mobile devices :/

Comment: Do you think that any of the issues that google pagespeed has found can cause the browser to crash/freeze? or are these just the animations please?

Comment: I would try to reduce the amount of animated elements to just the most necessary, normally I never use animated elements on mobile devices unless it is absolutely necessary or within the interaction. Let's say a menu that drop down or something. Also the audio is probably not necessary, it kind of annoy a lot of users, there should at least be a stop button that turns that off. That may also cause the crasches(?). Sadly I have no clue what is causing the crashes tho, but there are very much that is loading so just try to reduce as much as possible for mobile devices.

Comment: Removing the hover animation in mobile from the audio player toggle button is a good idea, really not necessary, thanks :)
Sad that mobile browsers (or the devices) are not that good, all my hard work was for nothing lol :/

Comment: I don't know if it may work on the newest devices, like iPad Air and stuff, but it didn't work on my old iPhone 4. There is a huge span of devices, like the really cheap android phones to the best Samsung and Apple products. But in general it is best to optimize for worst case scenario.